# javax.xml.transform.transformerexception while identifying an element using xpath in appium

Tags: java, android, xpath, qml, appium

I am getting 
`javax.xml.transform.transformerexception`

when I try to identify an element using `xpath` in `appium`. Below is the code,

```
driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//org.qtproject.qt5.android.QTSurface$VirtualChild[@index=0]")).click()
```

class name is `org.qtproject.qt5.android.QTSurface$VirtualChild`

Comment: You have got to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong code. Try this:

```
driver.findElement(ByXPath("//org.qtproject.qt5.android.QTSurface$VirtualChild[@index=0]")).click();
```

Comment: hmm.. I can't spot any difference between this in the code in the question ?

Comment: @Gaurav...i tried the code but it throws error.

I tried the below code  `driver.findElementByXPath("//org.qtproject.qt5.android.QTSurface$VirtualChild[@index=0]").click()`

but got the error again

`info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":32,"value":{"message":"Argument was an invalid selector (e.g.XPath/CSS).","origValue":"javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Extra illegal tokens: '$', 'VirtualChild', '[', '@', 'index', '=', '0',']'"},"sessionId":"e60ed97b-255d-4336-ac0e-5fd701fe95ff"}`

Comment: There is difference in your code and the code mentioned above. I don't know why you are using ByXPath.xpath. This is wrong

Comment: I tried the code posted by you but it throws error.